# Which gate is a microprocessor composed of?

Tags: transistors, microprocessor, logic-gates

Transistors make up a microprocessor. And they are used to make logic gates. But how does these transistors or gates make the information human readable? Which gate make up the microprocessor? Can one arrangement of gates do such computing? If not so, how does the arrangement of gate change?

Comment: It is very unclear what you ask. Since your claim "One arrangement of gates cannot do such computing." is false, it is difficult to answer this question.

Comment: A significant part of the micro processor can be described as a Counter,  Logic Unit(state machine) and Memory. These are linked in such away that as the Counter increments it points the logic unit either at memory to get the next instruction or clocks the logic unit through it's cycles. To understand this requires understanding of all 3 parts. Start with Memory then Counter and lastly the Logic Unit. Then it starts to make sense ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one arrangement of gates can do such computing.
But the answer to you question is to read a book about computer architecture.

I suggest you to read the Hennessy & Patterson book on computer architecture "Computer Organization and Design: the Hardware/Software Interface".

Answer (score 2):

Another book to consider is "[Code: The Hidden Language of Computer Hardware and Software](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735611319) (October 21, 2000) by Charles Petzold.  Despite the title, 4/5 of the book is on computer hardware, starting at a fundamental level.  Chapter 11 is titled "Gates (not Bill)" and that, plus the next several chapters that follow should answer some some of your questions.

[Petzold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Petzold) is a legend at Microsoft (a Microsoft MVP and one of seven "Windows Pioneers").  He wrote "Programming Windows" in 1988 which the first definitive reference book on the subject.  It is now in its [Sixth Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735671761).